# Why don't laravel tasks run with cron?

Tags: laravel, cron, task, laravel-7

I need to send emails from laravel tasks. I have this code for the task.

```
$schedule->call(function () {
  $date = now()->addDays(1);
  echo 'step 1';
  $appointment = Cita::whereDate('date', $date)->with(['patient'])->orderBy('date')->orderBy('hour')->get();
  echo 'step 2';
  foreach($appointment as $appt) {
    $data = array("name" => $appt->patient->name, "body" => 'Remember me');
    if ($appt->patient->email !== null) {
      Mail::to($cita->paciente->email)->send(new Reminder($data));
    }
    echo 'step 3';
   }
 })->everyMinute();
```

When running the command

```
php artisan schedule: run
```

manually in the terminal, everything runs correctly and I receive the email. Using mailtrap.

Then I add this

```
* * * * * cd / app && php artisan schedule: run >> /app/log.log 2> & 1
```

in crontab.

I send the command output to the log.log file to be able to view the echo.

and only gets to paint the first echo (step 1) and the rest of the echoes are no longer added to the log.

this is the result shown in the log.

```
Running scheduled command: Closure
step 1
```

No error is displayed and it does not send me the emails.
the version of laravel I use is 7.15.0

I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Anything in `storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: This is the error that appears to me.                                                                    ```local.ERROR: could not find driver (SQL: select * from `patient` where date(`date`) = 2020-09-24 order by `date` asc, `hour` asc) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 0): could not find driver (SQL: select * from `citas` where date(`date`) = 2020-09-24 order by `date` asc, `hour` asc) at /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671)
[stacktrace]```

Comment: Are you sure you're running correct version of `php` from your cron?

Comment: I don't know what the problem has been. But it was solved by running this command ```sudo apt-get install php7.3-pdo php7.3-mysql```   . The problem was solved but I would like to know why only with the cron command it gave me the error and in the rest of the situations everything goes well. thanks for your help.

Comment: That could be because you had two versions of PHP: one with pdo-mysql, and other without it. The one with pdo-mysql could be installed into `/usr/local/bin` and one without into `/usr/bin`. The user you ran `php artisan ...` could have `/usr/local/bin` in `$PATH` thus it ran first PHP, the cron could have ran `php artisan ...` under another user, without `/usr/local/bin` in `$PATH`, thus it ran another PHP (from `/usr/bin/`). When you later installed `pdo` and `mysql` extensions they got installed for `/usr/bin` version, thus it works now.